# замена текста replace

Tags: jquery

помогите пожалуйста с синтаксисом для глобальной замены, вариант не рабочий

```
var replaced = $(".plus").html().replace(/+/g,'плюс'); $(".plus").html(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var replaced = "+ + +".replace(/\+/g, 'плюс'); 
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо